# Finding value of a series in R without for-loop

Tags: r, vector

I am a newbie in R` and I found this problem:

> Calculate the following sum using R:
> 1+(2/3)+(2/3)(4/5)+...+(2/3)(4/5)...(38/39)

I was enthusiastic to know how to solve this without using a *for loop*, and using only *vector* operations.

---

### **My thoughts and what I've tried till now:**

Suppose I create two vectors such as

```
x<-2*(1:19)
y<-2*(1:19)+1
```

Then, `x` consists of all the numerators in the question and `y` has all the denominators. Now

```
z<-x/y
```

will create a vector of length `19` in which will be stored the values of `2/3`, `4/5`, ..., `38/39`

I was thinking of using the `prod` function in R to find the required products. So, I created a vector such that

```
i<-1:19
```

In hopes of traversing `z` from the first element to the last, I did write:

```
prod(z[1:i])
```

But it failed miserably, giving me the result:

```
[1] 0.6666667
Warning message:
In 1:i : numerical expression has 19 elements: only the first used
```

---

### **What I wanted to do:**

I expected to store the values of `(2/3), (2/3)(4/5), ..., (2/3)(4/5)...(38/39)` individually in another vector (say `p`) which will thus have `19` elements in it. I then intend to use the `sum` function to finally find out the sum of all those...

---

### **Where am I stuck:**

As described in the [R documentation](https://www.r-project.org/other-docs.html), the `prod` function returns the product of all the values present in its arguments. So,

```
prod(z[1:1])
prod(z[1:2])
prod(z[1:3])
```

will return the values of `(2/3), (2/3)(4/5), (2/3)(4/5)(6/7)` respectively which it does:

```
> prod(z[1:1])
[1] 0.6666667
> prod(z[1:2])
[1] 0.5333333
> prod(z[1:3])
[1] 0.4571429
```

But it's not possible to go on like this and do it for all the `19` elements of the vector `z`. I am stuck here thinking as to what could be done. I wanted to iterate all the elements of `z` one-by-one for which I created another vector `i` as described above, but it didn't go as I had thought. Any help, suggestions, and hints will be really great as to how this can be done. I seem to have run out of ideas here.

---

### **More Information:**

Here, I am providing with all the outputs in a systematic manner for others to understand my problem better:

```
> x
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38
> y
 [1]  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
> z
 [1] 0.6666667 0.8000000 0.8571429 0.8888889 0.9090909 0.9230769 0.9333333
 [8] 0.9411765 0.9473684 0.9523810 0.9565217 0.9600000 0.9629630 0.9655172
[15] 0.9677419 0.9696970 0.9714286 0.9729730 0.9743590
> i
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

---

**Short Note (controversial statement ahead):** This post would really have benefited from the use of [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), but unfortunately, *due to extremely heavy dependencies*, as is mentioned in several posts regarding inclusion of LaTeX on Stack Overflow (like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/8484779)), that is not a thing till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumprod` to get a cumulative product of a vector which is what you are after

```
p <- cumprod(z)
p
# [1] 0.6666667 0.5333333 0.4571429 0.4063492 0.3694084 0.3409923 0.3182595
# [8] 0.2995384 0.2837732 0.2702602 0.2585097 0.2481694 0.2389779 0.2307373
# [15] 0.2232941 0.2165276 0.2103411 0.2046562 0.1994087
```

A less-efficient but more generalized alternative to `cumprod` would be

```
p <- sapply(i, function(x) prod(z[1:x]))
```

Here the `sapply` takes the place of the loop and passes a different ending index for each product

Then you can do

```
1 + sum(p)
```